# Angularjs Directive Pagination reload pages not working

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I have copied working example for pagination & it is working fine.
But when I add more data (click add button in UI) means no of pages are changed then it didn't reflect in UI.
Please help to resolve this issue in Plunker.

[Pagination Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/oTtAwc?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simple, you don't recalculate number of pages, there is no watch or two-way data binding on it

http://plnkr.co/edit/AjjnZ7?p=preview

I've changed in my planker/app.js:

#### this

```
$scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil(myData.count() / $scope.numPerPage);
```

#### to that

```
$scope.noOfPages = function(){
  return Math.ceil(myData.count() / $scope.numPerPage);
}
```

and inside plunker/index.html

#### this

```
<pagination num-pages="noOfPages" current-page="currentPage" class="pagination-small"></pagination>
```

#### to that

```
<pagination num-pages="noOfPages()" current-page="currentPage" class="pagination-small"></pagination>
```